# Give selector.method as parameter, call it

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, function-pointers

I've got a function `$.doSomething()` which does some stuff and then should call other functions in the jQuery-form of `$('selector').function()`. I do not want `$.doSomething()` to know about what it's calling, that should be decided by the user.

I created a small example on JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/umonub/11/edit

Is it possible to store the call to `$('#foo').doStuff();` in a function-object and give it as parameter to a function which then calls it?

Here's the sample-code (in case somebody can't access JSBin or it gets deleted there):

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var callback = $('#foo').doStuff();
  $.doSomething(callback);
});


$.extend({
  doSomething: function(callback) {
    //do some stuff
    //call the callback
  }
});


$.fn.doStuff = function() {
  $(this).text("Stuff Done");
};
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="foo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just put `$('#foo').doStuff()` inside a function:

```
var callback = function() {
    $('#foo').doStuff();
};
```

Comment: ...why didn't I think of that? Thanks!